# Why would a partition be in use by the system if it isn't mounted?

Tags: filesystems, boot, partition

I've been migrating my system from btrfs to ext4 after running into performance issues with VMs. I have two hard drives in my laptop to work with. I've successfully moved my home partition, but the same steps I used aren't working for root.

Progress so far:

I've `dd`'d my root partition from `/dev/sda3` into `/dev/sdb3`. I modified `/etc/fstab` to the following:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# UUID=95f13c34-96ca-49e3-bcb2-ff594df31506
/dev/sdb3               /               btrfs           rw,noatime,ssd,space_cache,discard      0 0

# UUID=0fe04f59-599f-41e2-ac30-2ad0f17a9727
/dev/sda2               /boot           ext2            rw,relatime     0 2

# UUID=44741e0f-924a-4841-80ef-2132bef84182
/dev/sda4               /home           ext4            rw,noatime,discard      0 0
```

and run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux`. It seems to work. I'm able to boot by mounting the partition on the second disk. `df` shows:

```
$ df
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3        28G   18G  9.8G  65% /
```

So, clearly, `sdb3` is mounted, not `sda3`. Here's the problematic step: When I try to format `sda3`, which is supposedly unused, I get the following:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
[sudo] password for stew: 
mke2fs 1.42.11 (09-Jul-2014)
/dev/sda3 contains a btrfs file system
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
/dev/sda3 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

`sda3` is in use. How and why could it possibly be in use?

#### As per casey's comment, the output of mount:

```
mount | grep sd
/dev/sdb3 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,ssd,discard,space_cache)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
```

#### As per Warwick's comment, unmounting:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sda3
umount: /dev/sda3: not mounted
```

Mounting and umounting sda3 elsewhere works successfully, but changes nothing.

#### Update: More fishy behavior:

```
$ mount | grep sd
/dev/sdb3 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,ssd,discard,space_cache)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 mnt
[sudo] password for stew: 
$ mount | grep sd
/dev/sda3 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,ssd,discard,space_cache)
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard,data=ordered)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda3 on /home/stew/mnt type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,discard,space_cache)
```

After mounting sda3, sdb3 is no longer mounter. Weird, huh?

#### As per mikeserv:

```
$ rmmod btrfs
rmmod: ERROR: Module btrfs is in use
```

This is very much expected, since sdb3 is btrfs and supposed to be mounted to root. From my mkinitcpio.conf file:

```
MODULES=""
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

Comment: Try mounting it, then unmounting it. Perhaps a flag is set somewhere that makes it think it is mounted when it isn't. If it errors when mounting, hopefully it tells you the mount point that it thinks it is mounted at.

Comment: get the btrfs kernel modules/hooks out of initramfs. arch has a few of them. else blacklist it or `wipefs` on the disk to remove the superblocks... `rmmod`.... There are a lot of ways you could go, but they'll probably all come down to you not loading or unloading the module.

Comment: maybe some other program has /dev/sda3 opened

Comment: You really should be doing this from a live environment...

Comment: @case Done. /dev/sdb3 is clearly mounted

Comment: @Warwick Done. I can mount and unmount `/dev/sda3` and view its contents without any problems.

Comment: @mikeserv Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to know what's in my mkinitcpio.conf?

Comment: So can you `rmmod btrfs`? And yeah, it will likely be in that file if you have initramfs hooks for `btrfs` which commonly happens.

Comment: @jasonwryan Eh. That's probably a good idea. I actually did format sda3 from a live install enviornment. I then copied (cp -rp) the contents of sdb3 over. Couldn't boot.

Comment: @jasonwryan To be sure, I did all my dd'ing from that same install usb, but I feel safe trying to format a partition that's (supposedly) not being used while my system is up and running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. My bootloader wasn't configured properly. Sounds obvious, right? Modifying fstab doesn't quite qualify as configuring the bootloader. I had to change a line in `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cgf` to refer to correct boot partition.

That said, there was no need to boot off of the second disk in the first place. I could have avoided this problem by completing the whole process in a live environment and chroot-ing in to run `mkinitcpio`.

Comment: So you booted off sda3 then mounted sdb3 on / over top of it, which overwrote the mtab entry, hence the mount command output showing no sign of sda3.

Comment: @KyleJones Yup. That sums it up.